# What app is used to create these code preview images?

Tags: macos, export, preview

I see code preview images with macOS window style a lot on Instagram and Medium.com. What app is used to create these styled images:
[Code preview with macOS window style example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KKu9.png)

Comment: Are you just asking how to manually create a snapshot of code snippet on your Mac? Or are you asking how to do this programmatically? (FYI, if this isn’t a question how to do this programmatically, this is the wrong forum.) And when you ask about this code snippet “with the macOS window style”, are you asking how to format the code or how to show the chrome associated with the macOS window or both? Please clarify.

Comment: It's a service known as [Carbon](https://carbon.now.sh).

Answer (score 0):

This is done with a *quicklook* system extension which is based on the `highlight` command.  Select code file in the Finder and press the spacebar to activate *quicklook*, then use Screenshot to capture the window.  [image: helloworld.c code highlighting example]

One example of a quicklook system extension that allows style customization is https://github.com/sbarex/SourceCodeSyntaxHighlight